# QCA RSA Decryption

Tags: qt, rsa

I'm using QCA for encryption/decryption in my Qt application.
In the server side i'm using NodeJS with node-rsa module.
I can successfully encrypt from my Qt application encode it to base64 and decrypt with node-rsa.
The decryption operation fails at Qt side.

```
QByteArray imp;
imp.append(data_from_nodejs);
QString data_to_decrypt = QByteArray::fromBase64(imp);
QCA::Initializer init;
QCA::PrivateKey pk = QCA::PrivateKey::fromPEM(private_key); //pk.canDecrypt() return true
QByteArray inter;
inter.append(data_to_decrypt);
QCA::SecureArray array(inter.data());
QCA::SecureArray array_out;
if(!pk.decrypt(array,&array_out,QCA::EME_PKCS1_OAEP)){
    qDebug()<<"decryption failed";
}
```

> data_from_nodejs :
>   "\"VoXLeXxC9eX+KvFpS1lMjjmUPFDJHpwpBNtDPd6r8bodAwISWPMtoUyM1rUyucbaCraPL1oywQ5KweTCQYbxOwLwpBsR6oAIDNCYQ45xN3P5rPZgxWrjKre3HX6FSa8iefTcZWDD3977pCoBXsmaR3PHMHJMCMJE4OjRqEOfFNh66nRaVRb9f8ahJTijyMvGAQagKJd4+WrZVMJyYGxJTVTP3wQh6FbxdpIAbSEcYgshxcdJoRvmkfpr+OIhjaXrhDiSGl6f4kxzuMMk8wRgpZvXy5rrJ21dyKMzAZ/fA1uOrGwYygJoXNMC35MhZFCdw7XAG5hMBCVwGW5bGVa8fA==\""

and

> data_to_decrypt:
>   "V��y|B���*�iKYL�9��j�*��\u001D~�I�\"y��e�����*\u0001^ɚGs�0rL\b�D��ѨC�\u0014�z�tZU\u0016�\u007Fơ%8����\u0001\u0006�(�x�j�T�r`lIMT��\u0004!�V�v�"

Thank you for your help.